# Login failed with php oop

Tags: php, html, oop

I am new to PHP OOP, from the tutorial I am following, I was able to create a class that controls log in, sign up, update, profile and change password. I imported the class to my new web project it registers users but doesn't allow them to log in. Please anyone can help me figure out why the log in failed?

---

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

if(Input::exists()) {
if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

    $validate = new Validate();
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'username' => array('required' => true),
        'password' => array('required' => true)
    ));

    if($validation->passed()) {
        $user = new User();

$remember = (Input::get('remember') === 'on') ? true :   false;
$login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), Input::get  ('password'), 
 $remember);

        if($login) {
            header('location: index.php');
            //Redirect::to('index.php');
        }else{
echo '<p><span class= "error">Sorry, logging in failed.</span></p>';
        }

    } else {
        foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
            //echo  "<span class=                    
   \"error\">$error,</span><br>";
        }
    }

} 
} 
?>

HTML5
```

---

```
<html> 
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-md-9">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" >
            <h3>SIGN IN PAGE</h3>   
                <div class="form-group">   
                    <label for = "inputUsername" class = "col-sm-2 control-    label">Username:</label>       
                    <div class="col-sm-10">          
                    <input class="form-control" id="focusedInput"     
type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username...">     
                    </div>    
                </div>    
                <div class="form-group">       
                    <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 control- 
label">Password:</label>       
                    <div class="col-sm-10">          
                        <input class="form-control" id="focusedInput"  
type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter last name..." >       
                    </div>    
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">       
                    <label for = "checkbox" class = "col-sm-4 control- 
label">       
                        <input type="checkbox" name= "remember"  
id= "remember">  Remember me!
                    </label>   
                </div>       

                <p>
                    <input type= "hidden" name= "token" value= "<?php echo  
Token::generate(); ?>">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull- 
right" id= "submit" value="Sign in" name "submit"> 
                </p><br>
                <div class = "col-sm-4 control-label">
                    <p><a href="changepass.php">Change password</a></p>
                    <p><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.row --><br><br>

    <hr>
</body>
</html>
`
```

Comment: Try to display all php errors and warnings to make it easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks a lot @kenorb I discovered the error, it came from my database arrangement.